# how can i access local variable out of a block

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject arrow;
    private Vector3 a;
    private float angle;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            a = Input.mousePosition;
            Vector2 difference = a - player.transform.position;

            GameObject Aprefab = Instantiate(arrow) as GameObject;
            rb2D  = Aprefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2D.AddForce(difference * 0.02f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(rb2D.velocity.y, rb2D.velocity.x);
        Aprefab.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, (angle * 180) / Mathf.PI);
    }
}
```

Currently, I am making an arrow shooter.
I want to set arrow heading continuously while flying.
so I need to access "Aprefab" GameObject out of `if` block.
but how?

Need some help

Comment: You already have that `arrow` GameObject field – just store it there?

Comment: arrow.transform = Aprefab.transform;

Comment: like this? this returns error..

Comment: Don't overwrite the prefab.

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon my comment: I've

- refactored the shooting stuff into another function
- added a list `arrows` to keep track of all the arrows fired (that `Shoot()` adds to)
- made `Update()` iterate over all the arrows and update them

I don't have Unity at present, and this is dry-coded, so there might be some bugs.
Also, you'll want to take care of cleaning stuff up from the `arrows` list at some point.

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    private List<GameObject> arrows = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
             Shoot();
        }
        foreach(var arrow in arrows) {
            var rb2D = Aprefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            var angle = Mathf.Atan2(rb2D.velocity.y, rb2D.velocity.x);
            arrow.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, (angle * 180) / Mathf.PI);
        }
    }

    private void Shoot() {
        var a = Input.mousePosition;
        var difference = a - player.transform.position;
        var Aprefab = Instantiate(arrow) as GameObject;
        var rb2D = Aprefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb2D.AddForce(difference * 0.02f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        arrows.Add(Aprefab);
   }
}
```

Comment: changed "var rb2D = Aprefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();" to "var rb2D = arrow.GetComponent" and it works. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @정래광 if it works, please accept the answer, it helps filter out which problems require assistance with. Thanks,

Comment: I am almost very first in here. How can i accept your answer ?